# Geb does not insert the text in frame's input field

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

I have the following setup on my page:

```
<html>
<body>
    <frame name="header" ></frame>
    <frame name="footer" ></frame>
    <frame name="inline" >

        <input type="text" id:"fname">

     </frame>

<body>
</html>
```

I want to write a text in the field with id

> fname

I have tried several options, but the following is the last one.

```
class PageWithFrame extends Page {
static content = {
    myFrame(page: FrameDescribingPage) { $('frame',name:'inline') }
   }
}

class FrameDescribingPage extends Page {
  static content = {
    framefirstname { $('input', id:'fname') }
  }
}

 ...
 ...


 Then:
     to PageWithFrame

       withFrame(myFrame) {
    framefirstname.value("Hallooo") 
  }
```

The code itsself is running successfully without any error. However it does not fill the input field. Debugging is also not giving much information either.

Does any one has an idea of what is going on here.

Comment: Are you sure your code runs without any issues? The following does not look like valid html to me: `<input type="text" id:"fname">` and this is not valid Groovy as far as I know: `$('input', id='fname')`. Or are these just copy and paste errors?

Comment: @erdi you are right. that was a typing mistake I made while editing. It is $('input', id:'fname')

Comment: so just for a sanity check, the browser console can find $('input', id:'fname') and in your test framefirstname.isDisplayed() returns true?

Comment: @Doug Clark The browser console can't directly find $('input', id:'fname') because it is in the frame. That is why I have to reference the frame first, with myFrame(page: FrameDescribingPage) { $('frame',name:'inline') }. **Justin Schoen** answer is in the right direction. The problem is how does the page receives the information about the frame's module in a way that I could manipulate the module's elements.

Comment: sorry, not your browser driver, but you manually going to this page. The browser should be able to find anything that is in the page. What I'm asking is are you sure your selector is returning something

Answer (score 0):

Geb has built in modules you can use for filling out fields, or selecting from a list, or selecting checkboxes, etc. You need the [Text Input module](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#code-textinput-code)

Modify your page object like below. This imports the TextInput module for use and then it initializes your 'framefirstname' content as a module, giving you access to various methods provided by Geb. As mentioned in a previous comment, adjust your 'framefirstname' content according to [Geb standards.](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#the-code-code-function)

```
import geb.module.TextInput
framefirstname { $('input', id:'fname').module(TextInput) }
```

Geb provides a .text function for text input modules so all you'll need to do in your test is the following, and it should set your input field:

```
framefirstname.text = "n"
```

Comment: The problem I have right now is how to inform the FrameDescribingPage about the module, then manipulate the elements of my module in my test. Since in this case the elements are in the frame, and myFrame can only receive page as parameter

Comment: By the looks of your html, 'framefirstname' should just be a piece of content on your 'PageWithFrame' page. Correct me if I'm wrong, or if I'm missing something, but I think if it was defined in the content on your 'PageWithFrame' page, you may not have the same issue.

Comment: Not directly.It is a piece of FrameDescribingPage. It is a content of PageWithFrame because of the reference to FrameDescribingPage. I have tried to pass the PageWithFrame  a module with the frame information, but I can't access the elements of the frame, in the test

Comment: Have you tried the following:

    class PageWithFrame extends Page {
      static content = {
        myFrame { $('frame',name:'inline') }
        framefirstname { $('input', id:'fname').module(TextInput) }
      }
    }

    Then:
     to PageWithFrame
     framefirstname.text = "n"

Answer (score 0):

So far you are doing it well. If the page in a new tab? if yes you could withNewWindow or withWindow